# Alarm application in Java with JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, concurrency, timertask

I want to create a Reminder application with a similar idea like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106446/an-alarm-application-in-java), but this implementation only have at most one alarm/reminder at a time (ie. when an alarm starts, we can only configure another alarm after the most recently fired alarm has finished). Where do I start if I want to implement an application that can fire off multiple alarms?

My initial idea is like this:

For example my reminder application has 10 alarms for today, 20 alarms for tomorrow, etc (a certain number of alarms at a certain day). Should I just create a fixed amount of threads and process the alarms one day at a time? Or maybe I can reuse a timer and timer task but dynamically change the delay value?  Please help shed some light for this.

Comment: You could define [quartz crontriggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) for your alarms, but that is a reasonably complex process that relies upon a third party library.  It would provide a lot of power and flexibility but may be overkill for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just create a fixed amount of threads and process the alarms
>   one day at a time?

No, just create a thread when it's needed, to be honest you can just have a clock checker within your application and a table or some data structure which holds type of alarm, time, whatever else there and create thread only when it's needed, it will play sound, wait for termination, etc. (basically user input) or just wait for it to die after it will be done with its work. You can have some kind of fixed iteration amount.

> Where do I start if I want to implement an application that can fire
>   off multiple alarms?

Think about what kind of features you want to add, this will pretty much shape design of your application, design yourself some kind of manager of alarms, and system to create an alarm at a certain time.

Make sure you use FXML and force yourself to keep things organized, since your application can get bigger as you go on and add additional features.

Think about what data will be shared between threads since it's highly possible that you will not like to let threads/alarms overlap each other // for instance when they will have "remind in 5 minutes" //, or just terminate alarm that's about to cross into another one, if user doesn't terminate its alarm within that period and it just keeps going and another one is gonna be started, make sure that there is an entity or some higher controller class which takes care of this. If you don't wanna limit this to some minute interval maximum.

This application that you have in your mind is quite small and trivial you might be able to avoid most problems.

**Keep it simple**, this might be a best advice anyone can give you.

Bud it's just my personal take on this, these kind of questions will attract opinion based answers.